# throws Uncaught Exception

Tags: android

I tried to insert web service data in SQLite DB . But it shows error while creation of DB.
with this i have attached my code and error.

public class Disclaimer extends Activity {

```
GPSTracker gps;
static String latlan;
DatabaseHandler db;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.disclaimer);



    /*Getting GPS Location and Address Convertion , Lat and lang*/

    gps = new GPSTracker(getApplicationContext());

    db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    //db = new DatabaseHandler();
    latlan=String.valueOf(gps.getLatitude())+","+String.valueOf(gps.getLongitude());
    Global.setlatlan(latlan);
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);
    try {
        List<Address> address = geocoder.getFromLocation(gps.getLatitude(),gps.getLongitude(), 1);

        if(address != null) {
            Address returnedAddress = address.get(0);
            StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Source Address \n\n");
            for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
            }

            String curadr = strReturnedAddress.toString();
            Global.setCurrAddress(curadr);
            }
        else{
            Global.setCurrAddress("No Address Defined");
            }
        } 
    catch (IOException e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }


    /*Getting Device ID */
    TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
    mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
    String devno = mTelephonyMgr.getDeviceId();
    //Global.setDeviceID(devno);
    Global.setDeviceID("359462040979303");

    /*Calling Setting Service Details */
    SettingsService set = new SettingsService();


    /*Button Action Activities*/

    Button agree = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnagree);
    agree.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            gps = new GPSTracker(Disclaimer.this);


            // check if GPS enabled     
            if(gps.canGetLocation()){

            /*   Include App Web Service for Settings and Current Location and DB Storage*/


                String Settingres = Global.getResult();
                //String Settingres =null;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Settingres, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                List<Details> contacts = db.getAllContacts();


                //check for setting result
                if(Settingres.equals(null)==true)
                {
                    /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "check DB", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    boolean val =contacts.isEmpty();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(val), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
                    if((contacts.isEmpty())==true)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your Application Settings Not Loaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for (Details cn : contacts) {

                                String log = "APP ID: "+cn.getAPPID()+" ,Unique ID: " + cn.getUniqueID() + " ,Driver Name: " + cn.getDriverName()+ " ,Vehicle Name: " + cn.getVehicleName()+ " ,Mobile number: " + cn.getPhoneNumber();
                                Log.d("Name: ", log);
                              //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), log, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                    }
                }
                else if(Settingres.equals("Device Not Updated")==true)
                {
                    if((contacts.isEmpty())==true)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your Application Settings Not Loaded.Contact Customer Care", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for (Details cn : contacts) {

                                String log = "APP ID: "+cn.getAPPID()+" ,Unique ID: " + cn.getUniqueID() + " ,Driver Name: " + cn.getDriverName()+ " ,Vehicle Name: " + cn.getVehicleName()+ " ,Mobile number: " + cn.getPhoneNumber();
                                Log.d("Name: ", log);
                              //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), log, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Store in Setting DB
                    if((contacts.isEmpty())==true)
                    {
                        db.addDetails(new Details(Settingres));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        db.dropAllTable(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addDetails(new Details(Settingres));

                    }

                    CurrentTime tim = new CurrentTime();
                    LocationService curadrloc = new LocationService("App Open");


                    Intent mainscr = new Intent(Disclaimer.this, MainScreen.class);
                    startActivity(mainscr);

                }

                /*List<Details> contacts1 = db.getAllContacts();
                for (Details cn : contacts1) {

                    Global.setAppID(cn.getAPPID());

                    String log = "APP ID: "+cn.getAPPID()+" ,Unique ID " + cn.getUniqueID() + " ,Driver Name: " + cn.getDriverName()+ " ,Vehicle Name: " + cn.getVehicleName()+ " ,Mobile number: " + cn.getPhoneNumber();
                    Log.d("Name: ", log);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), log, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                */


                /*// Call current location Service

                CurrentTime tim = new CurrentTime();
                LocationService curadrloc = new LocationService("App Open");



                Intent mainscr = new Intent(Disclaimer.this, MainScreen.class);
                startActivity(mainscr);*/
                //db.close();


            }
            else{

                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }
        }




    });

    Button disagree =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btndisagree);
    disagree.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });

}

public void currentdetail()
{
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);
    try {
        List<Address> address = geocoder.getFromLocation(gps.getLatitude(),gps.getLongitude(), 1);

        if(address != null) {
            Address returnedAddress = address.get(0);
            StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Source Address \n\n");
            for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
            }

            String curadr = strReturnedAddress.toString();
            Global.setCurrAddress(curadr);
            }
        else{
            Global.setCurrAddress("No Address Defined");
            }
        } 
    catch (IOException e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

}

My Errors are

some times like

```
10-25 11:03:26.580: W/dalvikvm(1101): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
10-25 11:03:26.580: E/AndroidRuntime(1101): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
10-25 11:03:26.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1101): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
10-25 11:03:26.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at com.example.routemytrip.Details.<init>(Details.java:22)
10-25 11:03:26.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at com.example.routemytrip.Disclaimer$1.onClick(Disclaimer.java:153)
10-25 11:03:26.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
10-25 11:03:26.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
10-25 11:03:26.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6540)
10-25 11:03:26.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
10-25 11:03:26.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
10-25 11:03:26.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
10-25 11:03:26.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
10-25 11:03:26.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
10-25 11:03:26.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
10-25 11:03:26.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
10-25 11:03:26.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
10-25 11:03:26.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
10-25 11:03:26.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
10-25 11:03:26.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-25 11:03:26.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-25 11:03:26.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
10-25 11:03:26.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-25 11:03:26.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-25 11:03:26.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
10-25 11:03:26.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
10-25 11:03:26.585: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-25 11:03:26.607: I/dalvikvm(1101): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
10-25 11:03:26.607: E/dalvikvm(1101): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

and sometimes like

```
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956): Leak found
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956): java.lang.IllegalStateException: /data/data/com.example.routemytrip/databases/RouteFetchMgr SQLiteDatabase created and never closed
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1694)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:738)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:760)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:753)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at android.app.ApplicationContext.openOrCreateDatabase(ApplicationContext.java:473)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:193)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at com.example.routemytrip.RouteDBHandler.dropAllTable(RouteDBHandler.java:86)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at com.example.routemytrip.MainScreen$7.onClick(MainScreen.java:415)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6540)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
10-25 11:03:08.965: E/Database(956):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

can anyone help me for solution

Answer (score 1):

The first exception looks like it is being thrown by your `Details` class, which you have not provided the source for.

The second exception is usually caused by not calling `close()` on your database:

- [What is “SQLiteDatabase created and never closed” error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632047/what-is-sqlitedatabase-created-and-never-closed-error)
- [Sqlite Database LEAK FOUND exception in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280345/sqlite-database-leak-found-exception-in-android)