# Duplicate Menu Items Showing Up and One Not Showing at All; Crashing as well

Tags: android

Okay, so I've been doing pretty well with developing my Android App but then I run into this issue. I tried to make another Menu Item to an Option Menu which I've never had problems with before but now, as described in the question, one of the items is showing up twice and another isn't showing up at all and then when I enter the Credits activity it crashes. Below is the codes for the res/menu/menu.xml And MainActivity.java (first one)

```
@Override 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater(); 
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu); return true; }

@Override 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
// Handle item selection 
switch (item.getItemId()) { 



    case R.id.quit: 
        return true; 

    case R.id.new_game: 
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, New_Game.class); 
        startActivity(intent); 
        return true; 
    case R.id.visit_site: 
        Intent inten = new Intent(this, Site.class); 
        startActivity(inten); 
        return true; 
    case R.id.stay: 
         Intent inte = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); 
        startActivity(inte); 
        return true; 
    case R.id.credits: 
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Credits.class); 
        startActivity(i); 
        return true; 
    case R.id.exit: 
        Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
        in.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); 
        in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
        startActivity(in); 
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
        return true; 



}return false;
}
```

Here is the XML Menu

```
 <menu 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item 
    android:id="@+id/visit_site" 
    android:title="Visit the Medieval Site!" /> 
<item 
    android:id="@+id/quit" 
    android:title="Exit">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/credits"
        android:title="Credits"
    />

    <menu 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item 
            android:id="@+id/stay" 
            android:title="Cancel" 
        /> 
        <item 
            android:id="@+id/exit" 
            android:title="Exit" />
            </menu>
    </item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/new_game"
    android:title="Start the Game"

      />


      </menu>
```

I set up the credits as just a normal "Hello World" Activity in the Java file for it Here is the Android Manifest declaration for the activity. I'm including this just in the case that the error was in there by chance.

```
<activity android:name=".Credits"
        android:label="Application Credits"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"    >
    </activity>
```

If anybody could please tell me where I messed up and what I need to do tof ix it.

Here is the Credits.java asked by Sam below

```
  package com.apw.games.rpg.medieval;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;

public class Credits extends Activity
{


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.credits);





}


}
```

Comment: No exit menu/button/option please, you will incur the wrath of the google android devs/advocates, especially Reto Meier.

Comment: Could you please provide the stack trace you are seeing?

Comment: Stack trace? What is that?

Comment: What does you log say, the LogCat tab in eclipse in case of android development, when it crashes, it will show a trace of the method call stack specifying where your code crashes exactly.

Comment: Well I'm using AIDE On my device can logcat be done there

Comment: Only if you have root with AIDE (see "more" in the menu). Or use an app like OS monitor where you can see the log cat afterwards. But while AIDE is great, amazing even on an android unit, real development problem solving pretty much requires a desktop setup.

Comment: Ill checl out OS mmonitor but I don't have access to a commputer

Comment: Okay so I used OS monitor and when it crashed I got this: [Warning] Threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception

Comment: And what is the text around that, what Exception and what class and line is mentioned? There you will find your crash problem.

Comment: its says (the full message) [Warning] dalvikvm(14926) Threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)

Comment: Sorry there should be more information available near that part, when the app crashes.

Comment: Just saying that the log should have more information when this crashes, around that line, the following lines after that for example. If not this is not enough information I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if this has any thing to with the R.java file because of the group thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your menu layout is incorrect. The problem is "Credits", you cannot have nested items: `<item><item></item></item>`. Either move "Credits" into the submenu or move it into the regular menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/visit_site"
        android:title="Visit the Medieval Site!"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/quit"
        android:title="Exit">
        <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
            <item
                android:id="@+id/stay"
                android:title="Cancel"/>
            <!-- I moved credits here -->
            <item
                android:id="@+id/credits"
                android:title="Credits"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/exit"
                android:title="Exit"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/new_game"
        android:title="Start the Game"/>

    <!-- Or you can move credits here -->           
</menu>
```

Notice the layers are `<menu> <item> <menu> <item>  </item> </menu> </item> </menu>`.

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you I didn't realize that had happened my mind has been fried from so much code today

Comment: it fixed the duplicates but not the crashing when I click the option menu icon to go to the credits

Comment: Ok, post your LogCat errors in your question so I can see what is happening.

Comment: Same exact info above in the original comments

Comment: 12/22/2012 18:59:38 [WARNING] dalvikvm(19467) threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)

Comment: Ok, there should be more to it, that is just the first line. See [throws Uncaught Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13062835/1267661) for examples.

Comment: Because of the group=0x400.... stuff I was wondering if it possibly had sommething to do with R.java

Comment: It was added to the question

Comment: I still don't see the cause of the error. What is the package name in your Manifest?